# Aggregate SOQL - How Many Fields Can Be Grouped?

Tags: soql, aggregate, group-by

As stated in the title, is there any maximum on the number of fields that can be passed into a `GROUP BY` clause? I can't find any documentation on it. For example, if I had the following query:

```
SELECT count(Id) records
FROM My_Object__c
GROUP BY Field1__c, Field2__c, ..., FieldN__c
```

what would be the max `N`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The maximum is 32 groupings. If you exceed this, you receive the following error:

```
System.QueryException: Group By must contain 32 fields or less
```

This *used* to be in the documentation, but I can't seem to find it now.

## Proof

```
Set<String> fields = lead.sobjecttype.getdescribe().fields.getmap().keyset();
Database.query('select id from lead group by '+string.join(new list<string>(fields), ','));
```